# Hit http url using python getting IOError

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I tried by hitting as below

```
import urllib
second_query="http://example.com"
pw = urllib.urlopen(second_query)
pw = pw.read()
print pw
```

I am trying to hit jira api -http://example.com but I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "abc.py", line 7, in <module>
        pw = urllib.urlopen(second_query)
      File "/abc/xyz/pqr/thirdparty/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url)
      File "/abc/xyz/pqr/thirdparty/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 203, in open
        return getattr(self, name)(url)
      File "/abc/xyz/pqr/thirdparty/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 358, in open_http
        return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
      File "/abc/xyz/pqr/thirdparty/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 371, in http_error
        result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
      File "/abc/xyz/pqr/thirdparty/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 683, in http_error_401
        errcode, errmsg, headers)
      File "/abc/xyz/pqr/thirdparty/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 381, in http_error_default
        raise IOError, ('http error', errcode, errmsg, headers)
    IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x138e26c8>)
```

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the error it's clear that you don't have the required authorization:

```
IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x138e26c8>
```

You have somehow to provide the necessary credentials... I'm quite sure however that Jira provides high level API to use its tools, so you don't have to use a low level approach.

Comment: Yes I am authorized to access api because I can run same api by giving proper credentialds in browser but python does not ask me for credentials.

Comment: how should Python ask you for credentials? It's a script, a program... it does what you write in the code... so, you have to provide your credentials programmatically :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with jira rest API, but perhaps you are needed to provide some kind of API key to use it? 401 http status code suggests that you are not authorized to perform the action you are trying to perform.

I would start with reading the docs: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest (try searching for /rest/auth/1/session)

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are trying to reach the host, you will need to try using the complete URL refer https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/.